# Close ngx bootstrap modal without closing the other bootstrap modal in angular 10

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, ngx-bootstrap

I have one ngx bootstrap modal which gets opened on top of another ngx bootstrap modal.If I close the top modal then it is closing the other modal also. I need only the top modal to get closed and not all.

Comment: Could you add some code? Would be easier to analyze your problem that way. But from hearing that I reckon it's the same modal reference that's used for creating both.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't you use the same references in your templates ?

like here : using the same `modalRef` :

```html
<button type="button" class="btn-close close pull-right" aria-label="Close" (click)="modalRef?.hide()">
    <span aria-hidden="true" class="visually-hidden">&times;</span>
</button>
```

A little bit of your code might help as well :)
Cheers

Comment: I have used different modalRef.

Comment: Ok then, you might want to isolate your issue in some kind of stackblitz or something, because without code we'll be blind :)